# Good tips/courses for using Adobe Audition to mix audio story in a 'film' style

Tags: film-sound-design, production-audio, film-mixing

I am wanting to mix down an audio story in Adobe Audition - but I want to use similar techniques as mixing for a stereo film.

Can anyone recommend good Youtube video tutorials, online courses, etc, that would show me the correct levels for mixing in this way, i.e. set the dialogue to x level, the sfx to y level, and the music to z level.

I have mixed previous audio stories and podcasts, but I just want to try bump it up a notch.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is no set formula for this. You have to...

a) train your ears

b) use your ears.

The only standard I would adhere to is to pick a loudness level and make sure your final mix conforms to that. -24 LUFS will be a good place to start. Always make sure that your dialogue is able to punch through the music and effects. Dialogue is king. You can use level changes and EQ "holes" to make this work better. Make sure your dialogue is good quality and mix it against good reference dialogue so that there is enough body.

Don't try and find a formula for this. There isn't one.

Get some good reference material, study it and make your final mix sound like the best of the bunch. Ear training is the only way.

Comment: Thanks very much Mark, I really appreciate it!

When you say, 'mix it against good reference dialogue' do you mean pick the best part of my own dialogue, and then use that as a benchmark for all the rest? Or do you actually mean, dialogue from somewhere else, like a movie, etc.

Thanks again!

Comment: The latter. Find some film dialogue that has been really well recorded and mixed. Play it through your monitors and learn how it sounds. This then becomes your reference point. You make everything you do sound as far as possible, like what you are hearing. References work well in both dialogue and music scenarios. Music mixers are always using reference tracks and mixes to help them build their own great mixes. Good luck with it all!